# VHDL. Alternating between components every other clock cycle

Tags: components, vhdl

I have a component I would like to have 2 instantiations for, and I'd like to alternate sending/receiving data from each one every other clock cycle.  Something like this:

```
component piece is
  port(
     clk  : in std_logic;
     a  : in std_logic;
     b  : in std_logic;
     c  : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     d  : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
end component;

piece_0  : if clk='0' generate
  U_0: piece
    port map(
      clk  =>  clk,
      a    =>  a,
      b    =>  b,
      c    =>  c,
      d    =>  d
    );
end generate;

piece_1  : if clk='1' generate
  U_1: piece
    port map(
      clk  =>  clk,
      a    =>  a,
      b    =>  b,
      c    =>  c,
      d    =>  d
    );
end generate;
```

---

When I compile I receive the warning `Condition in IF GENERATE must be static`.
When I synthesize it crashes...

Any ideas on how I can implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Should your `piece` not have some outputs?  And are you wanting to run one bit of code while clock is low and another while clock is high (so-called double-data-rate) - which is what your pseudo code looks like.  Or on alternate clock ticks, which is what your text says...?

Answer (score 1):

A `generate` statement is evaluated during compilation, so the value of a signal has no relevance. It is used to instantiate blocks of code, either optionally (in the case of `if ... generate`), depending on some static value such as a constant or generic, or in a loop (in the case of `for ... generate`), for repeated instances of the same block of code.

You are trying to use it to control behavior at runtime, which is not valid. What you want instead is to instantiate both components and select the output with a mux. As your `piece` component has no outputs, it's a little difficult to provide some code that directly applies to your question, but in general:

```
U_0 : piece
  port map (
    clk => clk,
    a   => a,
    ...
    q   => q0
  );

U_1 : piece
  port map (
    clk => clk,
    a   => a,
    ...
    q   => q1
  );

q_muxed <= q0 when clk = '0' else q1;
```

I've written the mux using a simple concurrent statement, but there are other ways to do it. You may also want to consider using a signal other than `clk` as your select/switch. Using `clk` in a logical operation in most devices may have undesirable consequences, if it works at all.

Comment: @user1993270: If the intention is to implement a Double Data Rate (DDR) output from a device, where the output value is different from high and low value of the clock, then you should take a look at the dedicated DDR output elements in the target technology e.g. the FPGA of choice, since this will ensure that it is implemented correctly by the synthesis tool.

Comment: The OP says "every other cycle"... not alternate clock edges.  Mind you the code implies different!